# C++ Problem with simple terminal pause function

Tags: c++

I found in several places that using `system("pause")`
is a bad habit. So I created a function to replace that. After researching a bit I came up with the following function:

```
void pause(std::string message) {
    std::cout << message;
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    std::cin.get();
}
```

It worked perfectly when I tested it, the message appears
(`std::cout << message`), pause and continue when I press enter.

The problem starts when I use more than one pause, after the second use of `pause()` or the third one I need to press enter more than once, the first one just skips a line and then the second one executes the function. I've read about clearing the buffer, but all the stuff I've found lands on the line:
`std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');`
already present in the code.
As for the rest of the code, I believe it doesn't interfere, since if I create a program that only has these functions, e.g.

```
pause();
pause();
pause();
```

it behaves the same, requiring multiple enters.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2022.

I tried several things, including removing the line `std::cin.ignore()`,
but that meant that when I had some other `std::cin`, such as asking the user for a choice, and right after there was a pause, it ran automatically, I believe that because of the buffer...

The proper way that the `pause()` function is supposed to work is that every time it's called, just hit "enter" once and the program continues.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: As a side note, since `pause` doesn't need to own the string it's passed, you should consider using either `const std::string&` or `std::string_view` for `message`.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce.   The same behaviour (waiting for two newlines) occurs on the first call, contrary to your description (that it only does that on second and subsequent calls).   In any event, your usage of `cin.ignore()` will read until it encounters a newline AND will discard it.  Then a call of `cin.get()` will wait for a second newline.  Remove the `cin.get()` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes doing things one step at a time, all by yourself, is the simplest solution:

```
void pause(std::string message) {
    std::cout << message;
    char c;
    while (std::cin.get(c) && c != '\n')
        ;
}
```

If the goal here is to read and throw away everything on `std::cin` until a newline is read, then that's what you do. Sure, one could try to dump the task at hand on `ignore()`, but these ancillary library functions typically have nuanced behavior that's rigid, inflexible, and sometimes it just doesn't fit in with the rest of the program, and the resulting workarounds make things only more confusing.

Read one character at a time. Stop when you've read a newline. Mission accomplished.

Comment: This may or may not be a good advice, but it doesn't answer the question.